# Switching from let's encrypt staging to production

Tags: lets-encrypt

I’m using ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with docker / docker compose and traefik. The setup to get certificates is working fine using the staging Let’s Encrypt caserver (https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory). All my specified hosts do get a Fake LE Intermediate X1cert. There are no errors in the logs.

I can however not enable Let’s Encrypt production certs.
In the traefik.toml file - [acme] I deleted the staging caserver uri: no error in the logs / no production cert (staging cert is still applied). Even when I add the Let’s Encrypt prod uri (https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory 2) although it should default, result is sill the same: no prod certs and acme.json still shows the staging uri.

The traefik [acme]:

```
    [acme]
    email = "someone@gmail.com"
    caserver = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory 2"
    storage="acme.json"
    entryPoint = "https"
    onHostRule = true
    [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"

    [[acme.domains]]
    main = "mydomain"
    [[acme.domains]]
    …
```

What am I missing? Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is solved. 
Delete the acme.json & recreate the file. Initially I deleted the content of the acme file but that did not work as explained earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the staging domain:

```
certbot delete --cert-name example.com
```

And then retrieve another certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. On a server I had issued a cert for 16 domains using the Let's Encrypt staging server using:

`sudo certbot --test-cert --apache  -d example.com -d www.example.com`

To switch over to Let's Encrypts production I ran:

`sudo certbot --force-renewal --apache  -d example.com -d www.example.com`

`force-renewal` did the trick. But don't run this to many times as you risk hitting LE's rate limit.